# Cant right click be performed in linux using swtbot?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, swtbot

I want to right click a context menu using swtbot, I am using the following code:

```
treeitem.setFocus();
treeitem.contextMenu("context_menu_text").click();
```

The above code works fine in windows, but in Linux it throws a widget not found error. 
treeitem is the project in Project explorer.
Here is the full code:

```
SWTBotView view_project_explorer = bot.viewByTitle("Project Explorer");
List<Tree> controls = new ChildrenControlFinder(view_project_explorer.getWidget()).findControls(WidgetOfType.widgetOfType(Tree.class));
SWTBotTree tree = new SWTBotTree((Tree) controls.get(0));
SWTBotTreeItem treeitem = tree.getTreeItem("myProject");
```

To get the tree I have also tried the bot.tree() method directly, still it works only on windows not on Linux.
Also, I don't have a shortcut for the context menu option that I want to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be a bug in SWTBot. You should report it: https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/Contributing#Report_a_bug_or_suggest_an_enhancement